# Highlighting does not work in Elasticsearch and PHP

Tags: php, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-5

I've just downloaded and installed the last version of Elasticsearch on my Windows machine. I did my first search queries and everything seemed to work ok. However. when I try to highlight the search results, I fail. So, this is how my query looks like:

```
$params = [
    'index' => 'test_index',
    'type' => 'test_index_type',
    'body' => [
        'query' => [
            'bool' => [
                'should' => [ 'match' => [ 'field1' => '23' ] ]
            ]
        ],
        'highlight' => [
            'pre_tags' => "<em>", 
            'post_tags' => "</em>",
            'fields' => (object)Array('field1' => new stdClass),
            'require_field_match' => false
        ]
     ]     
]

$res = $client->search($params);
```

On the whole the query itself works nice - the results are filtered. In the console I see, that all documents indeed contain "23" value in their `field1` field. However, these tags - `<em></em>` are simply not added to the result. What I see is just the raw value in `field1` like "`some text 23`", "`23 another text`". It is not what I expect to see - "`some text <em>23</em>`", "`<em>23</em> another text`". So, what is wrong with that and how can I fix it?

Comment: It looks like `pre_tags` and `post_tags` may expect an array...can you try wrapping both in `em` strings in `[]`?

Comment: Did you try running that query outside PHP? (Like using the Sense plugin in Kibana or a simple `curl` command.) Does the highlighting work?

Comment: @Andrei Stefan. No, I have not tried that yet.

Comment: @Sam. It does not help. I checked it. I get filtered results, but without any highlighting

Comment: @Andrei Stefan. I tried curl, but it works really terrible on Windows. I'm not able to make requests that contain -d flag and some json body - on Windows in this case I'm getting some parse errors.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

[From the manual](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.0/search-request-highlighting.html):

1. The value of `pre_tags` and `post_tags` should be an array (however if you don't want to change the `em` tags you can ignore them, they already set as default).
2. The `fields` value should be an array, key is the field name and the value is an array with the field options.

Try this fix:

```
$params = [
    'index' => 'test_index',
    'type' => 'test_index_type',
    'body' => [
        'query' => [
            'bool' => [
                'should' => [ 'match' => [ 'field1' => '23' ] ]
            ]
        ],
        'highlight' => [
            // 'pre_tags' => ["<em>"], // not required
            // 'post_tags' => ["</em>"], // not required
            'fields' => [
                'field1' => new \stdClass()
            ],
            'require_field_match' => false
        ]
     ]     
];

$res = $client->search($params);
var_dump($res['hits']['hits'][0]['highlight']);
```

### update

1. Did a double check, the value of the field in the `fields` array should be an object (which is a requirement, not exactly the same as other options).
2. The `pre/post_tags` can also be strings (and not array).
3. Did you check the correct response? `$res['hits']['hits'][0]['highlight']`

> The important thing to notice is that the highligted results **goes into the `highlight` array** - `$res['hits']['hits'][0]['highlight']`.

Comment: Thanks! I will check it in a minute.

Comment: Unfortunatelly, it is not working. Now I'm getting this error message `[highlight_field] Expected START_OBJECT but was: START_ARRAY`. So, I think, there is some trouble with `'field1' => []` in your example. By the way, in docs it looks like so `"fields" : {  "content" : {} }`. I see no arrays here.

Comment: While, this structure is working - `'fields' => ['field1' => (object)[]]`. But still, neither default pre_tags and post_tags (when I ignore them), nor implicit `'pre_tags' => ['<em>'], 'post_tags' => ['</em>']` work.

Comment: @Jacobian, check the update please. Which version of the php library you use?

Comment: I installed the library with composer. The file looks like `{"require": {    "elasticsearch/elasticsearch": "~5.0" }}`

Comment: Seems right. Did you check `$res['hits']['hits'][0]['highlight']` for the highlighted results?

Comment: I've just checked! Now I see, that it is what I need! Thanks! I did not know that highlighted results go separately from _source. But still thanks!

Comment: Added a clarification regarding this :)